# How to implement tool tip in quill editor toolbar

Tags: angular, ionic4, quill, ngx-quill

We are using **"quill": "1.3.7"** version of quill editor in Ionic 4 application. We need to show tool tip for toolbar options. Is there any possible to enable tooltip for toolbar options.[Here attached the quill editor sample screen for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DORSH.png)

Comment: Why you need to display tooltip on a mobile application ? You're not supposed to interact with your mobile app with a mouse / cursor. Tooltip is only showed when mouse is hovered over an object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to display tooltip on web application.

Comment: You can try marceloloureiro's CSS hack method https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/235#issuecomment-726935121